# How should I play the Old Benoni Defense as both White and Black?

Tags: opening, learning, theory

```
[FEN ""]

1. d4 c5 2. d5
```

A lot of people play it against me as black, and I am also interested in it for both sides.

What are some of the main lines?  Also, what are some of the key positions and ideas?

Answer (score 6):

As white I have had a pretty easy time following up with the moves c4 - Nc3 - e4 - f4. Black will usually play e6 and exd5 - respond with cxd5. White ends up with a ton of space in the center. Look up the Taimanov variation in particular.

Basically I got this from MCO15 - the author mentions that many players use a different move order to reach the Benoni just to avoid this setup (they wait for white to play Nf3 blocking the f pawn).

Comment: I assume you meant to include `c4` among the moves in the setup you recommend, yes? (Either that or "respond with `cxd5`" after `...exd5` is a typo.)

Comment: @EdDean You are correct, I meant to include c4 :)

Answer (score 3):

> How should I play the Old Benoni Defense as both White and Black?

**Aggressively.**

Let me justify that a little. The Benoni is a *very* combative opening from both sides of the board. Many lines are extremely sharp, especially in the Old Benoni where White has all kinds of weapons at his disposal, like the ultra-sharp Taimanov (`1.d4 c5 2.d5 Nf6 3.c4 e6 4.Nc3 exd5 5.cxd5 d6 6.e4 g6 7.f4 Bg7 8.Bb5+`):

```
[Opening "Benoni, Taimanov Variation"]
[FEN "rnbqk2r/pp3pbp/3p1np1/1BpP4/4PP2/2N5/PP4PP/R1BQK1NR b KQkq - 2 8"]
```

In [modern lines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_Benoni), Black usually waits a move or two before playing `...c5`, to avoid some of the more popular "anti-Benoni" systems. Specifically, Black often wants White to commit a Knight to `f3`, so that there's no immediate fear of `f2-f4`. However, the Old Benoni is certainly still playable as long as you're ready for a highly tactical struggle.

---

### General Thoughts

In the main lines, Black usually plays `...e6` and then exchanges his e-pawn for White's d-pawn. This gives Black a queenside majority and White a central/kingside one. Black will then blockade the advanced d-pawn by playing `...d6`, and then usually fianchetto the King Bishop to take advantage of the strong diagonal controlled by his pawns on `c5` and `d6`. Meanwhile, White will use his advantage in space to make threats in the center and on the kingside.

This opening presents a variety of opportunities for tactical combinations. Because the center is semi-closed by the pawns on `c4`, `c5`, `d5`, and `d6`, it can be difficult to effectively switch pieces from one side of the board to the other, especially for Black, who has less space in which to operate. This tends to result in a game where counterattack is easier and more productive than defense.

---

### As White

White's most important positional advantage in the Benoni is his central pawn majority. In particular, the threat of White's eventual `e4-e5` is often a major point of contention for the early part of the game. White normally will castle kingside and play `Re1` to support this advance, and may also play `f2-f4` as well.

As the game progresses, White may also find a variety of very strong central outposts for his Knights, depending on which pawn advances Black ends up making. `c4` and `e4` are often good candidates, and sometimes even `b5`.

White enjoys extra space in the center and on the kingside, so his general plan is usually to pressure the center until he can either break through there, or spill over onto Black's castle. Besides the `e4-e5` pawn push, White may also put pressure on Black's backward pawn on `d6` with moves like `Nc4`, `Nb5`, and sometimes `Bf4`.

Since Black will frequently be trying to make headway on the queenside, White has an interest in preventing him from gaining much space over there. To this end, White often plays `a2-a4` and may try to land a piece on `b6` to prevent Black's `b7-b5`. If White can manage to maneuver a *Rook* to `b6`, Black will be very hard-pressed to hold onto his backwards d-pawn. Tactics involving sacrifices on `d6` are also relatively common, where White can make his central pawns into passers by force, and from there drive the game home.

```
[White "Jonathan Penrose"]
[Black "Mikhail Tal"]
[FEN "1rb1r1k1/2qn1pbp/3p2p1/1pnP4/2p1PP2/2N1B1NP/1PB2QP1/R4RK1 w - - 0 1"]

1.e5!
```

---

### As Black

Black has two key weapons in this opening: his queenside pawn majority and the half-open e-file. Because White's pawn center is fairly advanced, these two factors can combine to allow Black to undermine the White center with well-timed queenside pawn thrusts (`...c5-c4` is often a very potent threat), or else simply break through on the queenside while White is occupied elsewhere.

As his opponent will often be looking to play `e4-e5`, Black should usually put some effort into preventing this move, either by pressuring the `d5` pawn or (more usually) by contesting `e5` itself, taking advantage of the half-open file against White's pawn on `e4` (in lines where White plays `f2-f4`, this pawn is even *backwards*, making it even more of a target). Black normally castles kingside and plays `...Re8` relatively early to assist in this endeavor.

White's d-pawn is a bit of a thorn in Black's position, making it sometimes unclear where Black should place his queenside minor pieces. Black's Queen-Knight often develops to `d7` and eventually to `e5`, to blockade White's `e4-e5` advance, but sometimes instead Black can play `...Nb8-a6-c7` to put some pressure on `d5` and support a `b7-b5` advance, or this Knight may land on a `b4` outpost after White has played `a2-a4`. Black's Queen Bishop usually gets played either to `g4` (and then is often traded for a White Knight on `f3` to make `e4-e5` more difficult), or to `d7` to support the queenside attack.

Of course, kingside action is not at all out of the question for Black; the half-open e-file gives him some good options on that side of the board as well. In particular, Black's powerful Bishop on the long diagonal constantly threatens to slide into a very strong outpost on `d4`, and Black's Knights often land on the kingside anyway in the course of natural development.

```
[White "Kalju Vark"]
[Black "Mikhail Tal"]
[FEN "r1b1r1k1/pp1nq1bp/3p2p1/2pP1p2/1nB1PP2/P1N1BNP1/1P2QK1P/R6R b - - 0 1"]

1...fxe4! 2.Ng5 Nd3+! 3.Kg2 Nf6 4.Ba2 Bg4 5.Qd2 h6 6.h3
```